# Asking a question you want to answer

Tags: discussion, etiquette

What's the etiquette for asking a question you want to answer?

Let's say one has a piece of advice one thinks would benefit the community. Would it be acceptable to post a question and then immediately answer said question?

Assume the question would not be a duplicate and would be of sufficient quality to garner additional answers from the community.

Comment: have you asked it yet? I know it's allowed but haven't actually seen anyone do it, should be interesting

Comment: Under the 'ask question' button there is even a checkbox which allows you to ask and answer at the same time: http://i.stack.imgur.com/75YfV.png

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered clearly and completely in the help center: "*[Can I answer my own question?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)*"

Comment: I would consider asking in chat first and get some help to make sure its not a duplicate.

Comment: Related Meta StackExchange Question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stack Exchange policy explicitly says it's OK to ask a pedagogical question and answer it yourself. Others can also answer, of course, and your answer gets voted on just like any other answer (and independently from voting on the question).

Take the time to make it a well-written question and a well-written answer.

Comment: @chrisG While the site clearly allows the practice, I believe the practice is often viewed in an unfavorable light.  Unless your answer question and answer are both high quality, you should expect to see some downvotes.